# Is it okay to use two prepared statements within same try-with-resources block

Tags: java, mysql, database, prepared-statement

Well this method is working except that it makes me think I'm not doing it correctly. I have 2 tables related where

One subject has **many** school year. *(a subject can have many or can belong to different school years)*

One school year has **many** subjects

**Subject**

```
code PK
creator
dateCreated
description
name
units
yearLevel
```

**SchoolYearSubjects**

```
id PK
code FK
dateAdded
schoolyear
```

Here's the method.

```
public Boolean add(){
        Boolean success ;
        String SQLa = "INSERT INTO subject(name,code,units,description,yearlevel,creator) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        String SQLb = "INSERT INTO schoolyearsubjects(code,schoolyear,addedBy) values(?,?,?)";
        try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(SQLa);
                PreparedStatement ps2= con.prepareStatement(SQLb);){
          //a.)Prepare ps1
            ps1.setString(1,subjectName );
            ps1.setString(2,subjectCode );
            ps1.setInt(3, subjectUnits);
            ps1.setString(4, subjectDescription);
            ps1.setString(5, subjectYearLevel);
            ps1.setString(6, Login.getUsername());

          //b.)Prepare ps2
            ps2.setString(1,subjectCode);
            ps2.setString(2, schoolYearStart+"-"+schoolYearEnd);
            ps2.setString(3, Login.getUsername());

          //c.) execute both statements
            ps1.executeUpdate();
            ps2.executeUpdate();

            success = true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            success = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getClass()+" "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return success;
    }
```

I'm kind of hesitant to stick with having 2 prepared statement inside one method.

How can I ensure the successful execution of BOTH statements considering that `code` column is `Foreign Key` and that both has to execute within the same function?
Also, to add, the `add()` method is tied to just one button.

Please give me advice and correct me if there's anything I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider separating the `INSERT` statements if for no other reason than it would allow to handle failures separately in your calling code.  Currently, you would have to use an error code to distinguish one failure from another because a single boolean cannot convey this.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in executing two preparedStatements, but please don't forget to close the created `PreparedStatement` and `Connection` objects. Otherwise it will be resulting in an sqlError.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with two prepared statements in one block.

Guaranteed execution of multiple is what you call a "transaction" in SQL, and in Java, you can do it the following way (starting inside your try block):

```
     con.setAutoCommit(false);  // switch to transactional mode
     ...
     ps1.executeUpdate();
     ps2.executeUpdate();

     con.commit();              // commit the transaction
 }
 catch(...) {
     con.rollback();            // undo everything that happened
 }
```

Note, that you'll have to move your connection object to the outside of the try-with-resources, so that you have access to it in the catch-block. (Which you usually would do anyway, as a connection is an "expensive" object that normally has a longer life.)